# open image in canvas via url

Tags: javascript, html, url, canvas

I have been trying to open an image in canvas using a web url. Perhaps i am not using something well, what i have done is:

```
<script>
     function Draw_url_to_canvas(url1,name_of_canvas){
         var myCanvas = document.getElementById(name_of_canvas);
         var img3 = new Image;
         var ctx2 = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
         img3.onload = function(){
             ctx2.drawImage(img3,0,0); // Or at whatever offset you like
         }
         console.log(url1);
         img3.src = url1;
     }
</script>
<input type="text" name="url-pass" id = "url-pass"></input>
<button type="button" onclick = "Draw_url_to_canvas(document.getElementById('url-pass').value,'drawCanvas')">Pass url-photo to canvas</button>
```

I am trying to use this weburl: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Fw3rEXlvPTZnBINU5odWdXSUU/view?usp=sharing which i guess is valid for this work, though it has not worked till now. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code ?
Any errors ?

Comment: No errors at least to me..

Comment: Thank you if you put it as an answer i will be happy to accept it

Comment: That url does not point to an actual image, it points to an image view area, you need the direct image url

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: You need to use an URL that ends with .png, .jpg or any other image file names. For example: http://giraffopia.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/mad-cow-2.jpg Also you code above doesn't have any <canvas>-tags, you have those, right?

Comment: @Niddro No it does not work for me. Can you upload an example on js fiddle in which this is working?

Comment: @mpla_mpla, here http://jsfiddle.net/Niddro/u0022vjd/